# Button triggering a specific message from the user

Tags: button, message

I've been trying a messenger chatbot from a Taiwanese company, but I found it not so funny to play: Is it possible to design a button with a text on it which will trigger an automatic message with a different text from the user?

F.e. something like:

Button text: OK >>>> Text: I'm not sure I can help, but I'll do my best.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a button within messenger you add a postback value which is going to be post to your webhook when someone clicks on the button. You can then test the specific value to act upon it. IF source === "MY_SPECIFIC_VALUE_BEHIND_BUTTON" THEN ...